# What's the difference between ちゃんと, きちんと, きっちり and ぴったり?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

The four of `ちゃんと`, `きちんと`, `きっちり` and `ぴったり` all seem to mean something like "perfectly", "precisely" or "exactly", and there seems to be a lot of similarity between their definitions.

Daijisen says that all three of [`ちゃんと`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&index=11991200&pagenum=1), [`きちんと`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A1%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8&stype=0&dtype=0) and [`きっちり`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8A&stype=0&dtype=0) can mean something like "without disorder and well arranged" and [`きっちり`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8A&stype=0&dtype=0) and [`ぴったり`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%B4%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A&enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0) "without deviation", but I think they're used in different ways.

I think just from the way I've seen them used that `ちゃんと` might often, though not always, be close to "(do something) the way you're supposed/expected to", `きちんとした` "spotless", `きちんと` "to the letter", `きっちり` "firmly" and `ぴったり` "(suits) perfectly"/"perfect (match for)", but I'm not really confident and I don't have sources to back it up.

What is the difference between them and how do their usages differ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first two are used in contexts like: "do it properly."

> ちゃんと手を洗ってください
>
> きちんと部屋を掃除してください。

To me, it seems that きちんと implies more concentration/involvement. The result is cleaner, more polished.
Thus, ちゃんとできた would be "I did it as required", while きちんとできた would be "Not only did I do it as required, but I also paid attention to every detail."

The last one is used to express a perfect fit.

> このズボンがぴったり合う

I've never used/noticed きっちり, so I won't discuss it.

Comment: きっちり is a colloquial form of  きちんと but has a flavor of Kansai dialect. http://www.google.co.jp/url?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Da9EPVp_dZF4&rct=j&sa=U&ei=wYvtT_rZJIramAXjqoTFDQ&ved=0CCEQtwIwAA&sig2=UFjLAUB_RxvA94av8n_D_g&q=%E5%BC%95%E3%81%A3%E8%B6%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A4+%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8A&usg=AFQjCNHsus0o2vnBvQo9IPqCrokfsG3v-Q